# Include html part in a mail with python libgmail

Tags: python, html, gmail, mime, libgmail

I've a question about its usage: i need to send an html formatted mail. I prepare my message with

```
ga = libgmail.GmailAccount(USERNAME,PASSWORD)
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative') 
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
...
ga.sendMessage(msg.as_string())
```

This way doesn't works, it seems can't send `msg` with sendMessage method.
What is the right way? : D

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to `libgmail` from sourceforge, you need to compose your messages with the [email module](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html#module-email).

Generate the HTML message as a [MIME document](http://docs.python.org/library/email.generator.html), and include it as a part of a [multipart MIME message](http://docs.python.org/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart).  When you have a fully constructed multipart MIME, pass it along as a string to the `libgmail` constructor, using to `.as_string()` method.

An [example in the doc](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html#id4) contains the code for a similar requirement:

```
# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
...
# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
# ... text and html are strings with appropriate content.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Now i have the msg object, but i don't know how pass it to libgmail methods to send mail, like
     libgmail.GmailAccount(USERNAME,PASSWORD)
     ga.sendMessage(msg.as_string())
doesn't works :/

Comment: try to create a "GmailComposedMessage" from the string, and then try to send this object.